# Interpolate and Smooth Data Between Two Logarithmic Equations in Python

Tags: python, interpolation

I have several equations as follows:

```
windGust8 = -53.3 + (28.3 * log(windSpeed))
windGust7to8 = -70.0 + (30.8 * log(windSpeed))
windGust6to7 = -29.2 + (17.7 * log(windSpeed))
windGust6 = -32.3 + (16.7 * log(windSpeed))
```

where `windSpeed` is the wind speed from a model at 850mb.

I then use lapse rates from a model to determine which equation to use as such:

```
windGustTemp = where(greater(lapseRate,8.00),windGust8,windGustTemp)
windGustTemp = where(logical_and(less_equal(lapseRate,8.00),greater(lapseRate,7.00)),windGust7to8,windGustTemp)
windGustTemp = where(logical_and(less_equal(lapseRate,7.00),greater(lapseRate,6.00)),windGust6to7,windGustTemp)
windGustTemp = where(less_equal(lapseRate,6.00),windGust6,windGustTemp)

return windGustTemp
```

When I plot these equations as filled contours on a map there are sharp gradients as you would expect. What I would like to do is interpolate between these equations and maybe smooth a little to give a clean look to the graphic. I assume I would use scipy.interpolate.interp1d, but I am not sure how I would apply that to this circumstance. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT to add output image example**

This is an example of the output image generated currently. You can see how abrupt the edges are. I want to interpolate and smooth out this data.

[image: Output Example]

There are data points every 1 km with the model data. For each point it is first determined what the lapse rate is...let's say 7.4. Then based on the logic equations above, it knows to use the equation associated with the lapse rate between 7 and 8. It then finds the model wind speed for that point, plugs it into the equation and gets a number that it plots on the map. This is done for all the model data points and generates the above image.

Comment: In this form it is realy hard to understand what you want to achieve. I think minimal reproducible example would greatly benefit this question

Comment: @Marat Unfortunately the data is tied to our internal network, but I will add an image of what it looks like and perhaps that will help.

Comment: can you make a toy input that would result in the same problem?

Comment: @Marat I will try. In the meantime, I have added an output image showing what I get with the current code.

Comment: btw, `windGust7to8` values (70 and 30.8) seem higher than those both for `windGust8`  (53.3, 28.3) and `windGust6to7` (29.2, 17.7). Is it intended?

Comment: @Marat Yes, those are the correct equations generated from a logarithmic line in a Google Sheets graph.

Comment: @Marat The equations are all derived from this chart: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n5bki633w59rL5QiVsnKFp_vENYIqve9yP06In3PbV4/edit?usp=sharing